# Pygame Collision detection `colliderect()`

Tags: python, pygame

While going through the [docs of pygame](https://python101.readthedocs.io/pl/latest/_downloads/pygame192.pdf), there was a method of pygame called `colliderect()` that is used to test if two `rect` objects have overlapped.

> colliderect() test if two rectangles overlap
>
> colliderect(Rect) -> bool
>
> Returns true if any portion of either rectangle overlap (except the top+bottom or left+right edges).

In the last line , it said **except the top+bottom or left+right**

What does this statement mean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It means that the rectangles `r1` and `r2`:

```py
r1 = pygame.Rect(0, 0, 10, 10)
r2 = pygame.Rect(10, 0, 10, 10)
```

are not colliding. `r1.colliderect(r2)` returns `False`, even though `r1.left + r1.width` is equal `r2.right`.

That is because the `r1` covers the (x) region from 0 to 9 (inclusive) and `r2` covers the (x) region from 10 to 19 (inclusive).